# Vectorized loop for dynamic time wrapping

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to speed up the dtw(x, y, dist=lambda x, y: norm(x - y, ord=1))) at  https://github.com/pierre-rouanet/dtw/blob/master/dtw.py by vectorizing it. The first loop is easy, but I don't know how to vectorize the second one:

```
for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        D[i+1, j+1] += min(D[i, j], D[i, j+1], D[i+1, j])
```

The main problem is that, even if I iterate over i, each D[i+1, j+1] is dependant of D[i+1, j].

Is it possible to vectorize that, or do I have to use Cython ?

For x and y of shapes 1000x2, the original code take 15s, and my current code takes 1.8s, mostly in the second loop.

EDIT : minimal working example

```
np.random.seed(0); A = np.random.randn(4, 3)
r, c = np.array(A.shape)-1
for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        A[i+1, j+1] += min(A[i, j], A[i, j+1], A[i+1, j])
A
```

should give:

```
array([[ 1.76405235,  0.40015721,  0.97873798],
       [ 2.2408932 ,  2.2677152 , -0.57712067],
       [ 0.95008842,  0.79873121, -0.68033952],
       [ 0.4105985 ,  0.55464207,  0.77393398]])
```

Comment: Could you turn this into a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), giving the input `D` and the expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally did it! The solution was to iterate over the diagonals. The indices were hard to get right. Thanks everyone!

```
r, c = np.array(D.shape)-1
for a in range(1, r+c):
    # We have I>=0, I<r, J>0, J<c and J-I+1=a
    I = np.arange(max(0, a-c), min(r, a))
    J = I[::-1] + a - min(r, a) - max(0, a-c)
    # We have to use two np.minimum because np.minimum takes only two args.
    D[I+1, J+1] += np.minimum(np.minimum(D[I, J], D[I, J+1]), D[I+1, J])
```

Comment: how much is the time improvement?

Comment: For two 1000x2 inputs : original code 15s ; after vectorization of the 1st loop 1.5s; final code 432ms (x35)

Comment: Can the first loop be removed altogether by changing the last line to: 
D[I+1, J+1] = map(norm, x[I]-y[J]) + np.minimum(np.minimum(D[I, J], D[I, J+1]), D[I+1, J]) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
D[1:,1:] += np.min(np.dstack((D[:-1,:-1],D[:-1,1:],D[1:,:-1])),axis=2)
```

Comment: Assuming `D[1:, 1:]` is prefilled cost matrix with pairwise distances, it does not work.